# How can I render user name from database inside h1 tag in react?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I want to render user name in the navbar if the user is logged in. If I use Normal Text inside h1, like User I get that in the browser but when I'm using {user.name} it's not getting me the name of user from database.

I have tried like this

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    return (
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Book Rooms
                </a>
                <button
                class="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        {user ? (
                        <>
                            <h1 style={{color: 'white'}}>user</h1> 
                        </>
                        ) : (
                        <>
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/register">
                                Register
                            </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">
                                Login
                            </a>
                            </li>
                        </>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `user` to the console? If it exists and if it has a property called `name`, then you can render it as `<h1 style={{color: 'white'}}>{user.name}</h1>`

Comment: yes. name property exists in the console. but if i use {user.name} it's not rendering the user name

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `<h1>` tag to

```html
<h1 style={{color: 'white'}}>{user.name}</h1>
```

Comment: I have tried like that. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to console.log the user before component rendering to confirm that the user object is present in the localStorage :

```js
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
console.log(user);
```

if you get a good looking result in the console then procede to use in in any part of the rendered component like so
`{user}`
for example:

```js
 return (
....
..
.
<h1 style={{color: 'white'}}>USERNAME: {user.name}</h1>
...
..
.
)
```

at this point if you cannot see the element on screen it's most likely due to bad css, perhaps the element is out of screen or hidden. From the ChromeDevtools Inspect panel search for USERNAME (given that you used my example from the previous line) and use the mouse to highlight where is the h1 located; fix the CSS accordingly.